# Trying a non-existing SE URL has the wrong link

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

Go to e.g. http://wrong.stackexchange.com/:

> StackExchange couldn't find wrong.stackexchange.com.
>
> The StackExchange site wrong.stackexchange.com doesn't exist yet.
>
> Would you like to [create it](http://beta.stackexchange.com/)?

"Create it" should link to http://area51.stackexchange.com instead of http://beta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seconded.

In addition, the design of that page is atrociously boring! It makes unicorns weep in despair.

Comment: Also, on my Google Search for a weeping unicorn, I came across this *bizarre* find. http://hebrewtattoo.net/?p=239 (NSFW)

Comment: And this: http://homesliceva.com/images/uploads/unicorn-pissing-rainbows_thumb.jpg

Comment: __I have never wanted to be able to downvote comments as much as I do right now.__

Comment: @Popular I agree they are both products of a very, very sick mind :)